# How to execute multi line sql in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I execute lengthy, multiline Hive Queries in Spark SQL? Like query below:

```
val sqlContext = new HiveContext (sc)
val result = sqlContext.sql ("
 select ...
 from ...
");
```

Comment: please improve your post, nobody wants to see screenshots of code

Answer (score 27):

Use """ instead, so for example

```
val results = sqlContext.sql ("""
     select ....
     from ....
""");
```

or, if you want to format code, use:

```
val results = sqlContext.sql ("""
     |select ....
     |from ....
""".stripMargin);
```

Comment: what is that pipe symbol for?

Comment: Pipe is needed for the `stripMargin`, e.g. see [oreilly multiline strings](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s03.html)

Comment: @KenJiiii You are right. I haven't replied instantly and forgot later, thanks for this clarification

Answer (score 6):

You can use triple-quotes at the start/end of the SQL code or a backslash at the end of each line.

```
val results = sqlContext.sql ("""
    create table enta.scd_fullfilled_entitlement as
    select *
    from my_table
    """);

results = sqlContext.sql (" \
    create table enta.scd_fullfilled_entitlement as \
    select * \
    from my_table \
    ")
```

Comment: Triple quotes (both double and single) can be used in Python as well. Also backslashes are obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Obsolete? Not exactly, according to the Stype Guide https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

```
val query = """(SELECT
      a.AcctBranchName,
    c.CustomerNum,
    c.SourceCustomerId,
    a.SourceAccountId,
    a.AccountNum,
    c.FullName,
    c.LastName,
    c.BirthDate,
    a.Balance,
    case when [RollOverStatus] = 'Y' then 'Yes' Else 'No' end as RollOverStatus
    FROM
    v_Account AS a left join v_Customer AS c
      ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND c.Businessdate = a.Businessdate
    WHERE
    a.Category = 'Deposit' AND
    c.Businessdate= '2018-11-28'  AND
    isnull(a.Classification,'N/A') IN ('Contractual Account','Non-Term Deposit','Term Deposit')
    AND IsActive = 'Yes' ) tmp """
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that the length is not the issue, just the writing. For this you can use """ as Gaweda suggested or simply use a string variable, e.g. by building it with string builder. For example:

```
val selectElements = Seq("a","b","c")
val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder
builder.append("select ")
builder.append(selectElements.mkString(","))
builder.append(" where d<10")
val results = sqlContext.sql(builder.toString())
```

Comment: Without val in lines with append :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above ways, you can use the below-mentioned way as well:

```
val results = sqlContext.sql("select .... " +
" from .... " +
" where .... " +
" group by ....
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your sql inside triple quotes, like `""" sql code """`

```
df = spark.sql(f""" select * from table1 """)
```

This is same for Scala Spark and PySpark.