# Spark Sql - Getting Syntax Error - EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I used the following code:-

```
results = spark.sql(
                    "   
                        select b.* 
                        from ( 
                                select a.*, dense_rank() over (partition by nm order by total 
                                desc) as rnk
                                from (
                                        select dt, code, nm, sum(num) as total
                                        from cases
                                        group by dt, code, nm   
                                    )a
                            )b
                                where b.rnk = 1
                                order by total desc, dt
                    "
```

Getting Syntax Error - EOL while scanning string literal. I don't think I'm missing any double quotes or parentheses.

Comment: Looks like python where multi line strings are started and ended using `"""` instead of just an `"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787972/how-to-execute-multi-line-sql-in-spark-sql